# If URL has X within the URL, then do Y

Tags: php

Right now I'm using this code which checks the url for `?spt=01`:

```
if(isset($_GET['spt']) && $_GET['spt']=='01'){ 
    include('01.php');
}
```

But, what I would rather do is check the URL up to the end of the filename.

Example:
`http://example.com/folder/subfolder/page-name-goes-here.php`

So how do I check the url for `-name-` and then i can execute the php `include('01.php')`?

Comment: try `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

Comment: @FuzzyTree how do I check this for -name- and if its in the URL execute code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` from the `$_SERVER` array http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: how do I check this for -name- and if its in the URL execute code?

Comment: well that variable should have the name of the file in it, so then you can just use `strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'-name-');` to check

you can see the documentation for how to use `strstr` here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: if it is a certain pattern like page-name-goes-here.php including 4 words and separated with dash then use $urlArr = explode('-', $reqUrl), then $urlArr[1] (second one) will be the 'name' portion and you can check however you like it. I am assuming this way since you insisted mentioning "-name-" in your comments.